# Does a Spring RestController supports multiple connection?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a simple Spring RestController like this:

```
@RestController
class APIController {

    @GetMapping(path = ["/hi"])
    fun sayHello(): String {
        doExpensiveTask()
        return  "Hello"
    }
}
```

suppose the `doExpensiveTask()` takes 1 second, does this mean that I can serve max 1 request per second? Or is spring spawning multiple threads to serve multiple requests?

Comment: Your servlet container does the multi threading. Tomcat by default allow 200 concurrent requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is handled by your servlet container.

Say if you hit your API simultaneously `1000` times and your servlet container has a thread pool of size say `500`. So `500` threads will start executing your requests and the rest of `500` requests will be queued till the time the threads are available again.